# Deploy .Net 4.5 WebApi project with WebDeploy using Docker

Tags: windows, iis, docker, asp.net-web-api, webdeploy

I am new to docker and trying to learn .Net 4.5 applications to go with Docker Windows Container on our on-premise data center. 
I followed link [http://fluentbytes.com/deploying-asp-net-4-5-to-docker-on-windows/#comment-530794][1]

Following is my dockerfile for getting necessary docker images all is good:

```
# GET BASE IMAGE
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
RUN dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:iis-webserver /NoRestart

# GET IIS IMAGE
FROM windowsserveriis
RUN dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45

# GET WEB DEPLOY INSTALLED
FROM windowsserveriisaspnet
RUN mkdir c:\install
ADD WebDeploy_2_10_amd64_en-US.msi /install/WebDeploy_2_10_amd64_en-US.msi
WORKDIR /install
RUN powershell start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i 
c:\install\WebDeploy_2_10_amd64_en-US.msi /qn' -Wait
```

Now the Problem: I use web deploy to create zipped folder, paramerter files and windows script command and then use ANOTHER DOCKER file to deploy my webapi and it is as follows:

```
FROM windowsserveriisaspnetwebdeploy 
RUN mkdir c:\webapplication
WORKDIR /webapplication
ADD InventoryService.zip /Default\Web\Site/InventoryService.zip
ADD InventoryService.deploy.cmd Default\Web\Site/InventoryService.deploy.cmd
ADD InventoryService.SetParameters.xml  
Default\Web\Site/InventoryService.SetParameters.xml
RUN InventoryService.deploy.cmd, /Y
```

and it fails with "InventoryService.deploy.cmd" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I spent a lot of hours googling and stackoverflowing but to no avail. Can you please throw some light on

1. How we will deploy webapi with .net 4.5" using container?
2. what I am doing wrong in above dockerfile?
3. I will like to deploy this webapi to use given port (i.e. 12345 and not 80), so how will we have to do it?

Your help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Comment: You should consider not installing Web Deploy in a container, instead build a new container each time the your IIS application changes. I believe this is inline with best practices: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/.

Comment: It looks like the full path the InventoryService.deploy.cmd is missing in the last line.